# Stack overflow with my destructor

Tags: c++, parsing, constructor, linked-list

this is my first post to stack overflow. I'm creating a program to parse text into a linked list alphabetically, and to keep track of the count of each word. The program runs fine (by fine I mean 15 minutes which is obviously slow and not using a strong data structure) until my program returns and tries to deconstruct the dynamically allocated memory. Could someone help identify what pieces of this code I may need to adjust to avoid overflowing my stack?

```
template <class T>
void WordList<T>::destroyWord(WordList<T> *node)
{
    WordList<T>* nodeD = NULL;
    for(; node != NULL; )
    {
        if(node == NULL)
            return;
        else if(node->mNext != NULL)
        {
            nodeD = node;
            node = node->mNext;
        }
        else    
        {           
           // We have found the node to delete.
           //destroyWord(node->mNext);
          if( node->mNext == NULL )
          {
               if( nodeD != NULL )
               {
                   nodeD->mNext = NULL;
                   delete nodeD;
                }
                else
                {
                    node = NULL;
                }
          }
          nodeD = NULL;
       }
    }

    // **********************************
    // Delete the node at the root.
    //delete node;
    return;
}
```

Here is my revised code, thanks guys!....

```
    template <class T>
    void WordList<T>::destroyWord(WordList<T> *node)
    {
        node = node->mRootNode->mNext;
        static WordList<T>* ptr = node;
        for(; node != NULL && node->mNext != NULL; )
        {
            ptr = node->mNext;
            delete (char*)node;
            node = ptr;
        }
        delete (char*)ptr;
    }
```

Comment: Unrelated to your SO, you can probably figure out why your `if(node == NULL)` will *never* be true.  I mention this because *simplifying code* is a good first step in finding bugs.

Comment: Please include your destructor of that template class too. I bet you call `destroyWord` in it. Why did you comment out some code which really changes the semantics? I'd start with some unit tests, going from simpler cases to more complicated ones.

Comment: Stack overflows are not as hard to catch and debug as some memory corruption errors. Simply set your choice of debugger in a mode that causes to hit a breakpoint when it receives the stack overflow exception. Then look at the code stack and you can even examine what is wrong.

Comment: I think recursion will better fit in this case.

Comment: @Jueecy.new: most probably some unbounded recursion causes the stack overflow in the end. There will be so many calls on the stack that it cannot hold more. During each function call, some information is placed onto the stack (return instruction pointer, pointers or values to the parameters). If you have an infinite recursion, it's just blink of an eye time to have a stack overflow.

Comment: @CsabaToth, it's not like an unbounded iteration is going to be any better.

Comment: @Jueecy.new: not better, but that would only cause either "hang"/unresponsiveness of the program, or it'd cause some exception related to indexing or resource starvation. But the stack overflow, is most certainly infinite recursion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would bet: your destructor most probably calls `destroyWord`. We can see that the `destroyWord` has a `delete nodeD;` statement. `nodeD` is type of `WordList<T>`, so this will cause a destructor call on `WordList<T>`, and that has a `delete nodeD;` as we have seen. There is our infinite recursion.

Comment: it isn't infinite. It will eventually stop when it reaches the last node. But call stacks are limited in their depth (obviously) so you can push enough data into your list to cause an overflow on the stack (in fact, it is trivial to do with a smart-pointer-managed linked list).

Comment: @WhozCraig: Are you suggesting that I would mean "inifinite" literally? I didn't know I have to explain this, but "infinite loop" and "infinite recursion" is theoretical. It means that you have a potential flaw which would lead to infinite recursion or loop, given that you have infinite size of memory and/or infinite time.

Comment: I'm suggesting when someone says "infinite" they mean it. The algorithm used here is not infinite. It can *potentially* reach the limits of the runtime it is participating in with an appropriate amount of list-data. Chasing the path of a self-referencing list node (this->next = this) is infinite. This algorithm is not. It is wrong; it is bugged; but it isn't infinite.